# How can I solve the issue I'm having when I use an LC filter with a multi-level inverter?

Tags: filter

First of all, we are here to learn and learn.

I am looking for filtering the voltage output of a multilevel inverter to get a pure sinewave.

I'd like a clear way to describe the steps that can be taken to get what I want.

I tried  by using a modified multilevel inverter with LC filter with utlizing these parameters

I followed one paper as a reference and used the same values.

L= 3e-3
C= 470e-6
Vin= 200v
frequency= 20 kHz
Rload= 100

However, the multilevel inverters signal is distorted, and the output voltage after the LC filter is not a pure sine wave.
These pictures are of a multilevel inverter signal without a filter and the second with a filter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You expect a 50Hz sine wave output but the LC filter's cutoff frequency (fc) is around 130Hz (there's also a resonant peak at fc). The output signal (2nd image) still has a lot of harmonics.

Comment: I will add the output voltage on the load that seems not a pure sinewave.
Could you please tell me how to calculate the FC?

Comment: @Salah 1/sqrt(LC).

Comment: You need a much higher switching frequency if you want anything like a decent sine output.

Comment: Could you please send the appropriate formulas which can use in this design?